# Angular 4 code is not Hitting the ASP.Net Web Api controller

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on a project where i have  to make a form . I can get all the required data from databae accuratelly after making change in it i have to save it in database. Code is working properly on front end while its not hitting the required  controller and method in Asp.Net web Api. No error is also showing here.Please let me know what i have to do.What i am missing. I am really worried

This one is my Api path which i have to hit

```
getlandingGatepassvalueByparameter(itemOrder:any){        
         let url="http://localhost:50366/api/CustomerOrder/SaveOrder"    
          return this._restService.Post(url,itemOrder);           

 }
```

The below one in my Post method

```
Post(url: string, data: any): Observable<any[]> {debugger;
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' 
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(url, data,options)
            .map((response) => {
                debugger;
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(e => {
debugger;
                return Observable.throw(e);
            });
    }
}
```

The below one is controller method which i have to hit controler name is CustomerOrder

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult SaveOrder(List<ItemOrder> itemOrder)
        {
            string result = null;
            //result = _customerOrder.SaveOrder(itemOrder);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else


            {
                return null; ;
            }


        }
```

[image: This is what I am sending]
[image: These Are the values which are passing]
[image: While after debugging I got this error on console]

Comment: Try: `public IHttpActionResult SaveOrder([FromBody()] List<ItemOrder> itemOrder)`

Comment: and the error is related to Image! Have you used anywhere?

Comment: I used it now same result

Comment: I just used Image on front end it have no connection with server  side. I used the why which you suggested but same out. Still no error and not hitting the controller

Comment: Can you share the screen? If you are ready with that then only! will see.

Comment: sure i can share it but how could you want to share it

Comment: are you familiar with Anydesk?

Comment: yes aware of that

Comment: Ok then share the Id

Comment: Share team viewer id

Comment: Connection is blocked until 11:23

Comment: ok i ll wait till then

Comment: Bunddle of thanks sir

Comment: Done by your suggested method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code should work, but you need to see what wrong by trying step by step.

You can try with `Promise`:

So your post method will be like:

```
Post(url: string, data: any): Promise <any> {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });

  return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), { headers: headers })
    .toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

// to handle the error
private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add [FromBody] in controller method:

```
 public IHttpActionResult SaveOrder([FromBody] List<ItemOrder> itemOrder)
```

2) call by converting object by json.stringify

```
getlandingGatepassvalueByparameter(itemOrder:any){        
         let url="http://localhost:50366/api/CustomerOrder/SaveOrder"    
          return this._restService.Post(url,JSON.stringify(itemOrder));           

 }
```

3) make sure your routing is properly configured in api application.

Comment: sorry  to say its same output

Comment: some time browser chaching issue so try to clear cache and also re build your api and angular application.

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting the request object. Right now it is an array. Try making it an object that contains an array type property.

Controller Action signature

```
public IHttpActionResult SaveOrder([FromBody] LargeOrder itemOrder)
{}

public class LargeOrder
{
    public List<ItemOrder> itemOrders {get; set;}
}
```

Angular code:

```
getlandingGatepassvalueByparameter(itemOrder:any){        
         let url="http://localhost:50366/api/CustomerOrder/SaveOrder"    
          return this._restService.Post(url,JSON.stringify({"itemOrders":itemOrder}));           

 }
```

Comment: Sorry to inform you that same response after using your suggested method.